# Listview get tag from first child view

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `listview` that gets populated from the internet and stores an `id` from each item received to a tag being populated in to my listview. I want to fetch more data periodically by using the `id` from the first child element in the `listview` as the start limit of a query to fetch new items. I have been using `getChildAt(index)` but that only works for visible items in the listview and so returns an incorrect `id`, how can I get the right `id` from the first child element of the `listview` or what would be an alternate way to store the id from the first child in the `listview`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: There are only as many child elements as on the screen (well, and one or two either side) due to view recycling, so you'll never be able to get the tag on the first child, were it to be viewed. What's the solution? You get the first element out of your adapter, or better still, the container from which your adapter fetches information to populate the view. Does this sound helpful?

Comment: Yes this is helpful as I was looking to confirm my suspicion of not being able to get this tag as well as a suggestion for an alternate solution. I will take a try at it.

Comment: @Tom ok that worked, thanks for the suggestion I was not even thinking about that lol.

Comment: Great. If you fancy an experiment to get more of the gist with listviews in android, it would be instructive to make a test list and set a recycleListener on it and log out what happens when you scroll- should explain a lot. In the mean time could you tell me what kind of adapter you use so I can post a fuller answer?

Comment: Oh well if that worked you could even post your own answer! :). Wonderful.

Comment: I am using a custom `BaseAdapter` to take in an object for loading into an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. The object stores a string for the image location and a string for the description, base your answer on that ^_^